# RVC / Python issue - more details in

Tags: python, numpy

I've downloaded **RVC** Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI, for voice changing using AI Models

It has its own python I guess inside a folder (runtime)

When I run the app **go-web.bat**, it says `RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf`

Python + Numpy and all other things needed are downloaded with the RVC, but I noticed that it was trying to locate numpy that's installed with the PC's python, the original one and not the one it came with (attached image of the python that came with RVC).

**go-web.bat file:**
`runtime\python.exe infer-web.py --pycmd runtime\python.exe --port 7897 pause`

it uses the python that came with it, but it doesn't use the numpy that came with it.

how can I tell runtime/python to use **runtime/Lib/site-packages/numpy**
and not the one on my PC?

I tried copying and pasting numpy that came with RVC app to my PC python, it needed more files. So I decided I won't copy anymore, I want it to use everything that came with the app within the directory.

Comment: Any reason you are not using virtual environment?

Comment: Not sure how to do that

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Great, but after that, when I open go-web.bat, it will open the runtime\python.exe, but it will look for the addons from the PC not from the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Just extracted the application on c: drive, it worked.
Don't know why python apps can have issues if used on different drives.